# How to take screenshot in NEXUS 5?

Tags: nexus-5, screenshots

I have one question How to take screen shot in **LG NEXUS 5**?

My device has Android 4.4.4 installed.

Any tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press and HOLD 'power key' and 'Volume down' key together.

Comment: I already done with this but i failed.

Comment: Well maybe you are trying to get screen shot in app which doesnt allow to capture sceen

Comment: No men. I trying to take screen shot of my home screen.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try to download app in play store which takes screen shot.

Comment: If you have any app link or name.please give me..

Comment: Sorry, no app in mind. Try Google :)

Comment: Yeah. [Just like that](http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_layxkurNJE1qzpwi0o1_500.jpg), right? :) @MD it's sometimes a "timing thing". Some devices are a little difficult with that, as you'll hardly manage to press both buttons at the exact same moment

Comment: Exactly! I found out that too, my Nexus was not able to take screen shot if I pressed power button down little little liiittle bit earlier.

Comment: What you also can try: Long-press the power button and check the "power menu" popping up. I don't know for the Nexus, but many devices have a screenshot option in there. Might be easier and faster to use with "tricky-timing-devices".